# how to keep only two specific words after each other

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want my dataframe start with Login then followed with Logout, and continues with Login  and Logout only.

for exammple (before):

[image]

output (after):

[image]

Comment: The before and after look identical to me.  Please fix your sample data.

Comment: It is edited now, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `View` rows and then filter consecutive `Login, Logout` rows:

```
df = df[df['B'].ne("View")]

m1 = df['B'].eq('Login') & df['B'].shift(-1).eq('Logout')
m2 = df['B'].eq('Logout') & df['B'].shift().eq('Login')

df2 = df[m1 | m2]

print (df2)
        B         C
0   Login  02:29:04
2  Logout  02:29:14
7   Login  02:38:45
9  Logout  02:39:05
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df.drop(df[df['B'] == "View"].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I need after each Login word the following word is Logout to be iterated over the entire dataframe, not a filtration process